# R - are there efficient ways to perform this repetitive task?

Tags: r, repeat

Using R, I'm trying to create a column of mean with multiple columns as follows. Are there any efficient way to perform this repetitive task?

```
df$c1mean = rowMeans(subset(df, select = c1_1:c1_5), na.rm = TRUE)
df$c2mean = rowMeans(subset(df, select = c2_1:c2_5), na.rm = TRUE)
df$c3mean = rowMeans(subset(df, select = c3_1:c3_5), na.rm = TRUE)
df$c4mean = rowMeans(subset(df, select = c4_1:c4_5), na.rm = TRUE)
df$c5mean = rowMeans(subset(df, select = c5_1:c5_5), na.rm = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can loop over the sequence from 1 to 5 with `lapply`, use `seq` to create the sequence from that value to 5, `paste` the 'c', select the columns of 'df', apply `rowMeans`, and assign (`<-`) the output back to new columns

```
df[paste0("c", 1:5, "mean")] <- lapply(1:5, function(i)  
            rowMeans(df[paste0("c", i, "_", i:5)], na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

This can be done with `grep`

```
nm1 <- paste0("c", 1:5)
df[paste0(nm1, "mean")] <- lapply(nm1, function(nm)
           rowMeans(df[grep(nm, names(df))], na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!